# adding EventLinsters when getting element using getElementsByClassNames()

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have some information rendered from my backend that is:

This fragment is generated as an array where in the form element for every such fragment has the same class, the only value that is changing is the value attribute for the checkbox which is hidden and contains the name of the event

I want to add an event listener to each of such form elements of the fragment

```js
var linkForm = document.getElementsByClassName("linkForm");
for (n = 0; n < linkForm.length; n++) {
  linkForm[n].addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const eventName = event.target.check.value;
    const link = event.target.linkInput.value;
    console.log(eventName, link, uid, email)
    const uploadLink = async() => {
      const response = await fetch(
        '/uploadLinks', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            event: eventName,
            link,
            email,
            uid
          })
        }
      );
      const resData = await response.json();
      if (ressData.token === 'done') {
        window.alert('That was a lot of work! well Done! link is uploaded')
      }
    }
    uploadLink()
  })
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="accordion">EventName</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <form class="linkForm">

      <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="EventName" checked/>
      <input name="linkInput" type="text" placeholder="Upload Your G-Drive Link" />

      <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">upload</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

but upon clicking the submit button the page refreshes even though I have set event.preventDefault().

**EDIT**

the fragments get fetched from the backend so it takes a while to load

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: can be a bit more elaborate please?

Comment: you can remove the code inside the add event listener

Comment: The page doesn't refresh for me.

Comment: Do you only have event.preventDefault() inside addEventListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution provided by @chrwahl is indeed much cleaner but the issue was not the event listener at all. Inside the edited part of my question, I mentioned that those HTML fragments are fetched from the backend so there was a delay and the entire script got executed even before the HTML part existed. hence linkForm was always assigned null. I created addEventListener part after the fetch statement that resolved the issue –

Comment: So, based on multiple AJAX request the form is build, adding more input elements. After that, the form could be submitted?

Comment: Or is the problem the order of the fragments. Maybe you could show what a fragment is and what it should end up looking like?

Comment: the given HTML fragment in the question is the fragment that is created after receiving AJAX responses. So what had to be done was somehow assign `linkForm` after the ajax is served and the fragment is created

Comment: I made some changes to my answer. I'm not able to guess exactly what you would like to do, but in the updated version a fieldset is disabled as a starting point and when the AJAX request is dine it will update a value and enable the fieldset

Answer (score 1):

The event listener for the submit event should be added to the form itself. Then the `event.preventDefault()` will work. I moved the uploadLink function outside the event listener callback. Then it can be used in other situations as well.

I changed your URL to a data URI representing the JSON object from the server, so that you can see that it works.

```js
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendbtn');
var linkForm = document.forms.linkForm;

sendbtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  uploadLink('test', 'link');
});

const uploadLink = async(eventName, link) => {
  // this will be returned: {"token":"done","somevalue":12}
  let response = await fetch(
    'data:application/json;base64,eyJ0b2tlbiI6ImRvbmUiLCJzb21ldmFsdWUiOjEyfQ==', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        event: eventName,
        link: link
      })
    });
  let resData = await response.json();
  if (resData.token === 'done') {
    window.alert('That was a lot of work! well Done! link is uploaded');
    linkForm.valuefromajax.value = resData.somevalue;
    linkForm.fs1.disabled = false;
  }
};


document.forms.linkForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  let eventName = event.target.check.value;
  let link = event.target.linkInput.value;
  let somevalue = event.target.valuefromajax.value;
  console.log(eventName, link, somevalue);
});
```

```html
<button id="sendbtn">Send AJAX request</button>
<form name="linkForm">
  <fieldset name="fs1" disabled>
    <input type="text" name="valuefromajax"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="EventName" checked/>
    <input name="linkInput" type="text" placeholder="Upload Your G-Drive Link" />
    <button class="btn-submit">upload</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah id go with this one here